# Writing a chemical equation with a reactant of unspecified chain length

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, acid-base, stoichiometry, titration

Would appreciate it if I got some general tips and hints and not the solution cause I'm trying to learn from this question :)

The question is as follows:

> 1. FA1 is a solution containing $\pu{5.00 g dm-3}$ of a dibasic acid, $\ce{HOOC-(CH_2)_n -COOH}$.
> 2. FA2 is a solution containing $\pu{5.00 g dm-3}$ of $\ce{NaOH}$.
> 3. $\pu{25.0 cm3}$ of the acid solution FA1 needed $\pu{17.0 cm3}$ of the sodium hydroxide solution, FA2, for complete neutralization.
>
> Determine the value of $n$ in the formula of the acid.

The issue I have is in starting the question. I genuinely have no clue how to start a chemical equation with something like $\ce{HOOC-(CH2)n -COOH}$. Tips and hints would be greatly appreciated thanks.

Comment: 1) Start by writing the equation of the reaction
2) from the volume added to achieve neutralization, you can write a relation between the quantities of matter so the unknown will be the molar mass of FA1
3) you will be able to determine FA1 since you know its structure

Answer (score 2):

> Tips and hints would be greatly appreciated.

My tips and hints for you (I apologize for if my tips and hints direct to me treating OP as a novice):

1. Your dibasic acid is $\ce{HO2C-(CH2)n-CO2H}$. Thus, $\ce{A^2-}$ in the equation $(2)$ of Karsten Theis's answer is $\ce{^-OOC-(CH2)n-COO^-}$.
2. Molar mass of this dibasic acid is: $2 \times (12+32+1) + 14n = 90 + 14n$
3. Find the concentration of FA2 solution in $\pu{mol dm-3}$ (in other words, in $\pu{M}$. Hence, you can find the the amount of $\ce{NaOH}$ (in $\pu{mol}$) in FA2 solution ($\pu{17.0 cm3}$).
4. Determine the amount of dibasic acid (in $m_\ce{H2A} \ \pu{ mol}$) in FA1 solution ($\pu{25.0 cm3}$) using the equation $(2)$ of Karsten Theis's answer.
5. Now, you can find $n$ using following equation:
   $$m_\ce{H2A} \ \pu{mol} \times \pu{(90 + 14n) g mol-1} = \pu{5.00 g dm-3} \times \pu{0.025 dm-3}$$

Since you have already calculated $m_\ce{H2A}$ in step 4, you can calculate the $n$ $(\pu{1.0 dm-3} = \pu{1000 cm-3})$.

Note that $n$ is an integer so final answer should be rounded to closest integer.

Answer (score 1):

> I genuinely have no clue how to start a chemical equation with something like $\ce{HOOC(CH2)_nCOOH}$. Tips and hints would be greatly appreciated thanks.

The only thing that an acid does in an acid/base reaction is to lose hydrogen ions. You can write the neutralization of a monoprotic acid with $\ce{NaOH}$ like this:

$$\ce{HA(aq) + NaOH(aq) -> A-(aq) + Na+(aq) + H2O(l)}\tag{1}$$

This is already balanced. For a diprotic acid, the unbalanced equation would be

$$\ce{H2A(aq) + NaOH(aq) -> A^2-(aq) + Na+(aq) + H2O(aq)}\tag{2}$$

It is possible to balance this even though we did not specify what $\ce{A}$ is.

$\ce{HOOC(CH2)_nCOOH}$ is a diprotic acid as well, so its neutralization is described by a similar chemical equation. The bothersome $\ce{-(CH2)_n -}$ group prevents you from counting atoms on both sides of the equation; however, as it does not partake in the reaction, you can ignore it - it will appear on the reactant and product side in the same form.

> Tips and hints would be greatly appreciated thanks.

You got some tips and hints in the comments how to proceed once you figured out the stoichiometry. Another way of stating the steps is:

1. Determine the mass of FA1
2. Determine the amount of FA1 (how many moles)
3. Determine the molar mass of FA1
4. Figure out what $n$ is

Comment: Thanks! This was helpful. Am I right to think that in this case A is OOC(CH2)COOH?

Comment: almost ! Here you assay a diacid $ \ce {H_2A} $ -> the group A would therefore be $ \ce {OOC-(CH_2)_n-COO} $

Comment: Ahhhh. So the salt that will be formed is Na2(OOC−(CH2)−COO) am I correct?

Comment: Yes, if you want to write it as salt. I chose to write it in the dissociated form in equation (2)